# Как отобразить воксели?

Tags: c++, 3d

Хочу понять, как пользоваться вокселями. Как всё это работает, представляю, а вот как это выразить в кусочке кода на c++ - не знаю. 
Буду рад любым объяснениям и отправкам на любые ресурсы (кроме поисковиков, разумеется).